# Modify the triggering event of an event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'd like to change the triggering event of a set of event handlers via jQuery.

For example, if I have:

```
<div id=abc>Hello world</div>
```

And

```
$("#abc").on("mouseover",alert);
```

Is there any way to reassign the `mouseover` event to `mousemove`? Note that it should not keep the original `mousemove` event.

(I want to be able to modify the behavior of an object on a site via a user script)

Comment: Also, for some reason, `$(...).data("events")` isn't working now. Any reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure it's as simple as this:

```
$("#abc").mouseover($("#abc").mouseout);
```

---

Turns out, it's actually not that simple. You want this:

```
$("#abc").data("events")["mouseover"][0].handler;
```

Comment: I tried that with `off(mouseover)`. Using Visual Event, I can see that the mouseover event is still there, and the mouseout event is an empty bit.

Comment: Let's see. Editing my answer.

Comment: Actually, I want to make a mouseover-->mousemove (just used a different example). I have this code, and I'm trying to run it on the SO main page: `$('.post-tag').each(function(){
$(this).mousemove($(this).mouseover);
$(this).off("mouseover");

});`

Comment: Hmm, for some reason, `data("events")` isn't working. I'll be back in half an hour and I'll investigate.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: On the SO main page, try this in your console `$($(".post-tag")[0]).data("events")`